# Cannot select an md-tab in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-material

I am trying to use Protractor to write end-to-end tests using Protractor. I've run into an issue where I am unable to click on an Angular Material `md-tab` item and have it load. Instead, when I click on it, I just get a blank area where the tab content should appear.

I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6375) that provided some CSS that supposedly fixes the problem, but even with the CSS my tab is still not loading. I have tried clicking the tab in the following ways:

```
        element.all(By.css('md-tab-content')).then (tabs)->
          #browser.executeScript("#{tabs[1]}.click();")
          #browser.actions().click(tabs[1]).perform()
          #tabs[1].click()
          browser.actions().mouseMove(tabs[1], {x: -20, y: -20}).mouseDown().perform()
```

All of these methods result in the same hanging issue. The CSS I added based on the GitHub response is:

```
md-tabs-canvas {
  // Keeps IE11 from making `md-pagination-wrapper` as wide as the page.

  align-items: inherit;

  md-pagination-wrapper {
      width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

If I use `browser.sleep(5000)` and manually click the tab rather than trying to click the tab through protractor, the tab loads perfectly, and the test continues on as expected.

Does anyone know how I can use protractor to click an `md-tab` element and have it load the content properly?

Comment: Just guess(This solved some of my similar problem), try to refresh  the page and click on the particular element!!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nick. I've tried refreshing the page before clicking on the element, but it still seems to just hang.

Comment: element.all(By.css('.md-tab-content'));
You were missing "." try this and can you please post your HTML code so that i can have mote picture.

Answer (score 0):

I click tab items in my e2e tests without any problems using the following

```
element(by.css('md-tab-item:nth-child(1)')).click();
```

Comment: Is there any way to select it by text?

Answer (score 0):

I got a great solution here. Just do `element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-tab-label', "<Tab Name>")).click();`